# Using MongoDB command in AngularJs to create array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In AngularJS, how would I use a mongoDB command to create an array? To sum this up in AngularJS, I want to run this MongoDB aggregate command:

```
db.table.aggregate([{$group : {_id : "$status", number : {$sum : 1}}}])
```

to retrieve results and then store them in a new array. Is this possible? If not is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS runs on client side and has no direct access to mongodb. You need to implement an API on server side to retrieve data from the database and send it back to the client over http.